# Product of all possible ranges in a sequence

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Given a sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, we want to compute
$$\prod_{\ell=1}^{n-1} \prod_{r=\ell+1}^n (\max(a_\ell,\ldots,a_r) - \min(a_\ell,\ldots,a_r)).$$

For example, given $1, 2, 4$, the result should be $6$, which is $(2-1)\cdot (4-1)\cdot (4-2)$.

I know how to solve this in $O(n^2)$ by computing the inner product in time $O(n)$. Given $\ell$, we scan the array starting at position $\ell$, keeping track of the minimum and maximum encountered so far. This allows us to compute each $\max - \min$ factor in $O(1)$.

Is it possible to compute the produce in time $o(n^2)$?

Comment: Given that you are multiplying $\Theta(n^2)$ factors, all of which could be different (imagine $a_i = i + \epsilon_i$ for some "random" small $\epsilon_i$), I'm not sure you should expect anything better than $o(n^2)$. Do you expect to be able to compute $\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (a_j - a_i)$ in $o(n^2)$?

Comment: 1. What's the context where you encountered this task?  Is this from a programming contest?  Can you credit the original source?  2. What model of computation are you using?  Are you assuming that multiplication takes $O(1)$ time no matter how large the numbers you are multiplying?  That doesn't seem realistic.

Comment: @D.W. 1. Context is an exercise from my teacher. 2. Yes, we assume multiplication takes O(1) time no matter how large the numbers are.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, thanks for your update. :)